# How to create a custom virtual touch keyboard on windows RT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, virtual-keyboard

I want to create a custom virtual touch keyboard on Windows RT, like the existing handwriting recognizing keyboard on Windows RT but use my own HWR algorithm. 
Is there anyone know any sample for this?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Did you figure out a method ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to replace the touch keyboard on Metro UX. You can create a custom keyboard for Windows 8 but not for RT.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't mean to replace the existing virtual keyboard. I mean to create a plugin key board, so I can switch between the existing keyboard and my keyboard to input text.